# Overloading Recursive Function C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I was working on implementing a basic Binary Search Tree.

And i have defined a recursive function for printing the tree in order

```
void printTree(Node *n){
    if (n){
        printTree (n -> left);
        n -> printNode();
        printTree (n -> right);
    }   
}
```

When calling this function i am generally nearly always going to be calling it with the initial value of Node *n being a pointer to the root node.

is it okay then to overload the function like this.

```
void printTree()  {printTree(root);};
```

is this the accepted way of dealing with a recursive function in which the  argument for the first invocation is always going to be the same/using the same pointer/variable etc.

Is there another way of dealing with situations like this, for example nearly all recursive functions i will be implementing for the binary search tree will fall into the same case. i.e. the argument for the first invocation is always the root node.

Comment: Are you always going to have _one_ tree in your program?

Comment: @Koborl Please do not forget to accept the answer you like the most

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is okay to overload it if `root` is member of the class and it is initialized in class constructor.

```
class Tree
{
  public:
    Tree() : m_root(new Node()) { }
    void printTree(Node *n);
    void printTree() { printTree(m_root); }

  private:
    Node* m_root;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The version that you presented has one big disadvantage: a call to `printTree()` will always print *one particular* tree. This makes your code almost impossible to reuse; what you will do if you need *two* trees in your program?

If you want to support several trees in your program, then whenever you need to print a tree, you will need to specify which tree do you need to print. A simple way to do this is to pass a pointer to a root node, but that's exactly what your original non-overloaded function does. So for such a simple case there is no reason to overload.

However, a more realistic situation might be that you have a separate `class Tree`, which is different from a `Node` class. In this case you might have `Tree::print(Node*)` to print a subtree and an overloaded `Tree::print()` to print the whole tree. In this case a typical usage will be along the lines of `tree.print();` and here `tree` variable already specifies which tree to print, and the overload makes sense and is handy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Using bootstraps for methods like this for certain data structures is 100% fine, probably even more efficient.

If this is the case, set up the class in a way so that the main `printTree` method is private and the bootstrap is the public method that gets called like this:

```
class Tree
{
    private:
        Node *root;
        void printTree(Node *n);

    public:
        ...
        ...
        void printTree();
};

void Tree::printTree()
{
    printTree(root);
}
```

Comment: `root` member shall be initialized in Tree constructor